# for loop expect results differents between interactive and script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

At this  link I've read the for loop management for except https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/for.htm

If you call expect and paste the code in in you get the correct behavoir :

```
@gigi:~$ expect
expect1.1> for {set x 0} {$x<10} {incr x} {
    puts "x is $x"
}+> +> 
x is 0
x is 1
x is 2
x is 3
x is 4
x is 5
x is 6
x is 7
x is 8
x is 9
expect1.2>
```

Instead if you pass it from bash script it goes to error:

```
^@gigi:~expect -d << EOD
> for {set x 0} {$x<10} {incr x} {
>     puts "x is $x"
> }
> EOD
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
missing operand at _@_
in expression "_@_<10"
    (parsing expression "<10")
    invoked from within
"for {set x 0} {<10} {incr x} {
    puts "x is "
```

Why this example work different?

Comment: `$x` is expanded inside here document.

Comment: Embedding Expect in shell is tricky. Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've got is that `bash` has expanded the variables in the here-doc that you put the script in before passing it to `expect`. From the `bash` manpage:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> > [*n*]**<<**[**-**]*word*
> >                    *here-document*
> > *delimiter*
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command  substitution,  arithmetic
> expansion,  or pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  If any part of
> *word* is quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal  on  *word*,
> and  the  lines  in  the  here-document  are  not expanded.  If *word* is
> unquoted, all lines of the here-document  are  subjected  to  parameter
> expansion,  command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character
> sequence **\<newline>** is ignored, and **\** must be  used  to  quote  the
> characters **\**, **$**, and **`**.

This means that one workaround is to use `expect -d << 'EOD'` instead of `expect -d << EOD`.

```sh
expect -d << 'EOD'
    for {set x 0} {$x<10} {incr x} {
        puts "x is $x"
    }
EOD
```

Another (inferior!) is to backslash-quote the `$` characters; it's inferior because real expect scripts often contain their own backslashes and things can get very ugly and complicated. However, the best is to do this:

**Put the expect script in its own file,** say `myfile.exp`, and call it like this: `expect -d -f myfile.exp`. Trying to put Tcl code inside Bash scripts like that is asking for trouble.

Note that this does mean that passing variables from bash is a little more awkward. But you gain by the vastly increased sanity of coding.